Help with integration over a triangular region.
I'm currently trying to wrap my head around double integrals over a triangular region, when you are given the vertices of the triangle. I need to do the integral
$$
\iint_D 2e^{-y-x} \,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $D$ is the region between the vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,3)$, and $(3,1)$.
I understand we need to intergrate between the lines $y=3x$ and $y=4-x$, and between the $x$ values of $0$ and $1$, but I can't seem to grasp how the integration works. From sketching out the triangle, I don't understand how does the region between the lines $y=\frac{x}3$ and $y=0$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$ just gets ignored?
Does anybody have an explanation for me to get my walnut-sized brain around this? Cheers in advance.

Who is saying the integral is $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=3x}^{4-x} 2e^{-y-x} , dy , dx \quad ?$$This domain lies outside of the triangle.

Without changing coordinates, for each $x$, we have to visit each $y$ in the region. The lower bound is consistent: $y = \tfrac13 x$, but the upper bound changes depending on which side of $x = 1$, we're considering.
So $D$ will have to be broken into $2$ regions: $D = D_1 \cup D_2$, where
$$
D_1 = \bigl\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1 \,\text{and}\, \tfrac13x \leq y \leq 3x \bigr\}
$$
and
$$
D_2 = \bigl\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 1 \leq x \leq 3 \,\text{and}\, \tfrac13x \leq y \leq 4 - x \bigr\}.
$$
You can drag the $x$-coordinate of the point to various values in this interactive visualization, and see the corresponding interval of $y$-values.

Since the vertical "seam" where the two regions meet is "infinitely thin" (it has measure zero), we don't have to be careful about including those points essentially twice when we break up the integral, so
\begin{align}
\int_D 2e^{-y-x} \,\mathrm{d}A 
&= \int_{D_1} 2e^{-y-x} \,\mathrm{d}A 
+ \int_{D_2} 2e^{-y-x} \,\mathrm{d}A \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_{\tfrac13x}^{3x} 2e^{-y-x} \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x
+ \int_1^3 \int_{\tfrac13x}^{4 - x} 2e^{-y-x} \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x. 
\end{align}

Method 1:

$$\color{red}{\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=x/3}^{3x} 2e^{-y-x} \, dy \, dx} + \color{blue}{\int_{x=1}^3 \int_{y=x/3}^{4-x} 2e^{-y-x} \, dy \, dx}.$$
Method 2:

$$\color{green}{\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y/3}^{3y} 2e^{-y-x} \, dx \, dy} + \color{orange}{\int_{y=1}^3 \int_{x=y/3}^{4-y} 2e^{-y-x} \, dx \, dy}.$$
The fact that the region of integration is symmetric about the line $y = x$ means that the setup is the same for both methods, except we just switch $y$ and $x$.  In the first method, you are integrating the function $f(x,y) = 2e^{-y-x}$ over a series of vertical strips extending from the bottom side of the triangle upwards.  In the second, you are integrating over a series of horizontal strips from the left side of the triangle to the right.  In both cases we have to split the region into two sub-regions because the upper limit of integration depends on which side of the triangle you are looking at.
In Method 1, the red region is specified by first taking an $x$-value between $0$ and $1$, and then for that $x$-value, the $y$-values range from $y = x/3$ (the bottom side of the triangle) to $y = 3x$.  For example, if $x = 1/2$, then $y \in [1/6, 3/2]$, corresponding to drawing a vertical line at $x = 1/2$ and finding the $y$-coordinates of where that intersects the triangle.  And when $x = 1$, this just gives $y \in [1/3, 3]$ as the diagram shows.
Similarly, in the blue region, $x$ ranges from $1$ to $3$, and if we choose, say, $x = 2$, then $y \in [2/3, 2]$, which is what you'd see if you drew a vertical line through the triangle at $x = 2$.

Thank you! This explanation has helped me wrap my head around it. I was trying to do the whole integration as one, but seeing it split up into two regions (x=0 to x=1, and x=1 to x=3) and doing the limits of integration seperately for each of the lines y=3x and y=4-x is a nice trick. Once again thank you!

The region is bounded by three lines $$ x+y=4,y={1\over 3}x,\ y=3x$$ We can change variables to $$u=x+y,\ v ={y\over x}$$ i.e. $$ x={u\over 1+v},\ y= {uv\over 1+v}$$Then the region can be described by  $$0\le u\le 4,\ {1\over 3}\le v\le 3$$ The determinant of the transformation is equal ${u\over (1+v)^2}.$ Hence the integral is equal $$\int\limits_0^4ue^{-u}\,du\ \int\limits_{1/3}^3{1\over (1+v)^2}\,dv \\ (-ue^{-u}-e^{-u})\Big\vert_0^4 \ {-1\over 1+v}\Big\vert_{1/3}^3={1\over 2}(1-5e^{-4}) $$

I like a more general method where you describe any position inside the triangle as a function of two arbitrary variables that vary between 0 and 1.

For example, the point $\boldsymbol{P}$ can be defined in terms of the three vertices of the triangle $\boldsymbol{A}$, $\boldsymbol{B}$ and $\boldsymbol{C}$ and two arbitrary variables $t$ and $u$.
$$ \boldsymbol{P}(t,u) = (1-t) \boldsymbol{A} + t \left( (1-u) \boldsymbol{B} + u \boldsymbol{C} \right) $$
Then you develop the differential area element for the region
$$\begin{aligned}{\rm d}area & =\left|\tfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{P}}{\partial t}\times\tfrac{\partial\boldsymbol{P}}{\partial u}\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =\left|\left(\mbox{-}\boldsymbol{A}+(1-u)\boldsymbol{B}+u\,\boldsymbol{C}\right)\times\left(t\,\left(\boldsymbol{C}-\boldsymbol{B}\right)\right)\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =t\,\left|\left(\mbox{-}\boldsymbol{A}+(1-u)\boldsymbol{B}+u\,\boldsymbol{C}\right)\times\left(\boldsymbol{C}-\boldsymbol{B}\right)\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =t\,\left|\left(\mbox{-}\boldsymbol{A}+(1-u)\boldsymbol{B}\right)\times\boldsymbol{C}-\left(\mbox{-}\boldsymbol{A}+u\,\boldsymbol{C}\right)\times\boldsymbol{B}\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =t\,\left|\left(\mbox{-}\boldsymbol{A}+(1-u)\boldsymbol{B}\right)\times\boldsymbol{C}-\left(\mbox{-}\boldsymbol{A}+u\,\boldsymbol{C}\right)\times\boldsymbol{B}\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =t\,\left|\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C}+\boldsymbol{C}\times\boldsymbol{A}\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u
\end{aligned}$$
and confirm the area of the triangle
$$\begin{aligned}area & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}t\,\left|\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C}+\boldsymbol{C}\times\boldsymbol{A}\right|{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =\left|\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C}+\boldsymbol{C}\times\boldsymbol{A}\right|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}t\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =\tfrac{1}{2}\left|\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C}+\boldsymbol{C}\times\boldsymbol{A}\right|
\end{aligned}$$
This means that the constant with the cross products inside the integral can be substituted with
$$\left|\boldsymbol{A}\times\boldsymbol{B}+\boldsymbol{B}\times\boldsymbol{C}+\boldsymbol{C}\times\boldsymbol{A}\right|=2\,area$$
so the area integral becomes $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}t\,\left(2\,area\right){\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u$
For this example
$$ \boldsymbol{P} = \pmatrix{x\\y} = \pmatrix{ t (2u+1) \\ t (3-2 u)}$$
which in this case it is $ \boxed{ area = \tfrac{1}{2} | -8 | = 4 }$ given that $A = (0,0)$, $B=(1,3)$ and $C=(3,1)$.
Now to perform the integral of $f(x,y) = 2 \exp( -x - y) = 2 \exp(-4 t)$ as follows. Note the variable substations $x= t (2u+1)$ and $y=t (3-2u)$ as described above when $\boldsymbol{P}$ was evaluated
$$\begin{aligned}value & =\left(2\,area\right)\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\,t\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =\left(2\,area\right)\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}2{\rm e}^{\text{-}4t}\,t\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & =\left(2\,area\right)\tfrac{{\rm e}^{\text{-}4}\left({\rm e}^{4}-5\right)}{8}\\
 & =\tfrac{area}{4}{\rm e}^{\text{-}4}\left({\rm e}^{4}-5\right)
\end{aligned}$$
The above evaluates with $area = 4$ as
$$\boxed{value={\rm e}^{\text{-}4}\left({\rm e}^{4}-5\right)\approx0.908422}$$

Appendix I
The 2D cross product is defined as
$$\pmatrix{A_x\\A_y} \times \pmatrix{B_x\\B_y} = A_x B_y - A_y B_x $$

If you wish to integrate with respect to $y$ first, you should have
$$\iint_T 2e^{-x-y} \, dA = \left\{\int_0^1 \int_\tfrac x3^{3x} + \int_1^3 \int_\tfrac x3^{4-x}\right\} 2e^{-x-y} \, dy \, dx$$
The limits on the integral should be clear from looking at a plot of the region $T$, and the other answers do a fine job of explaining this in more depth.

On the other hand, we can simplify the integral expression somewhat by enforcing a substitution that rotates $T$ counterclockwise about the origin by $\arctan\dfrac13$, the same angle that the line $y=3x$ makes with the positive $y$-axis. This would align $y=3x$ with the vertical axis in the new coordinate system. Let
$$(x,y) = \left(\frac{3u+v}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{-u+3v}{\sqrt{10}}\right)$$
Here's a plot of the rotated $T$ in the $(u,v)$ plane:

The area element is
$$dA = \left\lvert \det \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt3/2 & -1/2 \\ 1/2 & \sqrt3/2 \end{bmatrix} \right\rvert \, du \, dv = du\,dv$$
There's some additional effort required on your part to determine the new limits of the integral, but you will end up working with just one integral.
$$\iint_T 2e^{-x-y} \, dA = \int_0^\tfrac{4\sqrt2}5 \int_\tfrac{3u}4^{\sqrt{10}-\tfrac u2} 2e^{-\sqrt{\tfrac25} (2u+v)} \, dv \, du$$
